# Circular references in Nation-Town-Citizens chain

Tags: java

Say I have three classes, **Nation**, **Town**, and **Citizen**. A nation contains towns, and a town contains citizens.

```
public class Nation {
    Set<Town> towns;
}

public class Town {
    Set<Citizen> citizens;
}

public class Citizen {

}
```

Sometimes I need to know the nation a citizen belongs to. However, with the above implementation, there is no way of knowing that, unless I do this:

```
public class Nation {
    Set<Town> towns;
}

public class Town {
    Set<Citizen> citizens;
    final Nation nation;

    public Town (Nation nation) {
        this.nation = nation;
    }
}

public class Citizen {
    final Town town;

    public Citizen (Town town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public Nation getNation() {
        return this.town.nation;
    }
}
```

I'm often warned of staying away from "circular references." Does this constitute a circular reference? And if so, should it be avoided? And if it should be avoided, what is an alternative to this solution?

Comment: With the original implementation, it would be a two step process to get the Nation of a Citizen. For that, you need to 1- determine which town the citizen belongs to, and 2- what nation contains that town.

Comment: This is not a circular reference. Circular is when a refers to b and b refers to a either directly or through a chain of object(s). `a.memberName = b` `b.otherMemberName = something` ...  `someOtherStuff.someMemberName = a` What you are describing is a tree structure and by it's nature isn't circular.

Comment: I think there's circular dependency. check my comment on the answer given by @Mohammad

Comment: What is the difference between a circular reference and a circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

With the original implementation, it would be a two step process to get the Nation of a Citizen.

For that, you need to

1. determine which town the citizen belongs to, and
2. what nation contains that town.

So somewhere in your main class you would need to do the following to the details of a nation

```
    nations.get(towns.get(citizens.get(person)))  //--> gives you the Nation details
```

Comment: That's what OP has already implemented. He is looking for solutions that avoid the circular dependency

Comment: How is this circular?

Comment: As far as I understand, there's circular dependency, as 1) class Nation {Set<Town> towns;} Nation requires the class towns, 2) class Town {.. final Nation nation;..} Town requires the class Nation

Comment: From what I understand you're saying I should get the name of the citizen, then request the top-most class search through each nation, and have each nation search through each town, and have each town search through its citizens for a name match. This is a very performance heavy solution and I'd rather avoid it. The whole reason I want to include a back reference in each object is to eliminate this performance problem.

Comment: @RishiDua "He is looking for solutions that avoid the circular dependency" -- Not necessarily. I just want to know if my solution will introduce any problems down the line.

Comment: For this simple case using a back reference shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @RishiDua you are explaining how the writer's modified code is circularly dependant. I'm talking about the template not his implementation of the skeleton.

Comment: @user2301287 Searching through a `Set` is not performance intensive. Not at least for all the citizens in the world. In addition, I took that your concern was the circular dependency and not performance. The search involved in your first block of code takes precedence over the bad circular design.

Comment: @Mohammad The example I gave was simplified for this particular question. In reality, the game would include several more layers of classes, meaning several more sets. Would searching through Game->Maps->Map->Nations->Nation->Region->Town->Building->Citizen be a performance issue?

Comment: @user2301287 your question will remain unanswered if you plan on adding new assumptions to the original question.